# Join optimization PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables : Calls (10,000 rows) , CRM (25 million rows)
I want to do Calls left join CRM.

```
select * 
from calls a
left join crm b
on (
(a.customerID = b.customerID)
OR
(a.Number1 in (b.Number_A,b.Number_B))
OR
(a.Number2 in (b.Number_A,b.Number_B))
);
```

When I do just the customerID join, it runs fine. But the above code causes timeout and it crashes.

Comment: You should at least add EXPLAIN output (ie, run `EXPLAIN select * from ...`) to your question and describe the indexes you have. Do you have indexes on b.number_a and b.number_b, for example?

Comment: I have indexes on all join columns.

Comment: Your query does not have any filtering condition and is retrieving all the combination of rows that match the join condition. Are you sure you want to scan the whole table?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: With your query there can be up to 250 billion result rows. How many do you expect? If the current explain plan expects very many matches and you know that there will be only few, then installing `pg_hint_plan` and adding a rows hint to the query might help a lot.

Comment: What times out?  Client, server, network? And if the timeout is bothersome, why did you install it? What crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest multiple `left join`s:

```
select c.*, 
       coalesce(cc.col1, c1a.col1, c1b.col1, c2a.col1, c2b.col1)
from calls c left join
     crm cc
     on c.customerID = cc.customerID left join
     crm c1a
     on c.Number1 = c1a.Number_A left join
     crm c1b
     on c.Number1 = c1b.Number_B left join
     crm c2a
     on c.Number2 = c2a.Number_A left join
     crm c2b
     on c.Number2 = c2b.Number_B;
```

This can then take advantage of indexes on `crm(CustomerId)`, `crm(Number1)`, and `crm(Number2)`.

Comment: Will this cause dups?
I have indexes on all join columns

Comment: I don't think that works. If a call has one crm row matching the customerID and another crm row matching number1, then we get only one result row and the `COALESCE` only shows us one of the two col1 values.

Comment: @SaadAmir . . . It depends what you mean by "dups".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when replacing one query that contains two conditons with `OR` with two queries that get glued together with `UNION`, this results in a better execution plan. I have never understood why DBMS optimizers don't take this in consideration themselves. And I don't know whether this is true for PostgreSQL or not. But it may be worth a try.

In your case there is an outer join in the query. That complicates the matter. With the separate queries we may get both outer joined and matching crm rows for a call and must get rid of the former in that case.

```
select *
from
(
  select * from calls left join crm on crm.customerID = calls.customerID
  union
  select * from calls left join crm on crm.number_a = calls.number1
  union
  select * from calls left join crm on crm.number_a = calls.number2
  union
  select * from calls left join crm on crm.number_b = calls.number1
  union
  select * from calls left join crm on crm.number_b = calls.number2
) data
order by rank() over (partition by calls.id order by case when crm.id is null then 2 else 1 end)
fetch first row with ties;
```

For this to work fast you should have one index per column in the query, i.e. six single-column indexes.

Whether this is faster than your original query depends on a lot of things. Mainly: the fewer matches the better.

Comment: Just a note: `UNION` can be much more expensive than `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @The Impaler: Yes, I had this in mind. But I had to get rid of duplicate matches and duplicate mismatches before applying `RANK`. I don't know whether starting with `UNION ALL` instead and then applying `DISTINCT` later would make a difference. Maybe another option one could try.